# Linux LVM - PVID last seen on

Tags: centos, redhat, lvm

```sh
Devices file sys_wwid nvme. PVID last seen on /dev/nvme0n1p2 not found.
```

OR

```sh
Please remove the lvm.conf filter, it is ignored with the devices file.
```

Seems this is happening on RHEL 9 / CentOS 9.

Comment: Sorry, is this a question? Or an answer? Or are you documenting both for future googlers? If so, please rephrase your question into a proper question and then post your answer as an answer to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While awaiting a fix this can be bypassed by setting `use_devicesfile=0` inside of `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`

For more information on this issue you can see the BugZilla report here:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1965941

Comment: Perfect solution!!

Comment: Thanks Steven, this really saved me.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably caused by some outdated  *device  entries* in the *devices file* located in
`/etc/lvm/devices/system.devices`

You can remove those entries with the [lvmdevices](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvmdevices.8.html) command.

```bash
sudo lvmdevices --deldev /dev/nvme0n1p2
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. In mine case I executed this order of steps: `created partition /dev/nvme1n1p1 (type 8E Linux LVM). pvcreate /dev/nvme1n1p1, vgcreate vg01 /dev/nvme1n1p1,  vgremove vg01,  removed partition /dev/nvme1n1p1`.

So mine problem was deletion of partition without executing `pvremove` 1st.

Answer (score 0):

you may find that deleting the relevant wwn entry in /etc/multipath/wwwid is required (seems to persist across reboots ?) which is what finally worked for me